# Getting the flyout menu height same as the main menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was designing a flyout menu and wanted to make the sub-menu height equal to that of the main menu.

Here is the **html** code to the menu that I am working on

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="button"><a>Sub menu title 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Link1</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="button"><a>Sub menu title 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Link4</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="button"><a>Sub menu title 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the **css**

```
#nav {
top: 50%;
left: 0;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
#nav ul {
width: 200px;
background: #f9f9f9;
position: absolute;
left: -9999em;
}
#nav a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
#nav ul li {
position: relative;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
left: 200px;
top: 0;
}
#nav li:hover > a {
cursor: pointer;
}
.button a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

This is the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9mqy3r4q/).

Is there a way to get the height of the flyout be equal to that of the main menu

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `height` css property:

```
#nav {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
}
#nav ul {
    width: 200px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999em;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added JQuery tag to the question so giving a JQuery solution to this.

```js
console.log($('#nav').height())
var nav_height = $('#nav').height();
$('#nav ul').each(function(){
 $(this).css('height', nav_height+'px');
})
```

```css
#nav {
top: 50%;
left: 0;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
#nav ul {
width: 200px;
background: #f9f9f9;
position: absolute;
left: -9999em;
}
#nav a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
#nav ul li {
position: relative;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
left: 200px;
top: 0;
}
#nav li:hover > a {
cursor: pointer;
}
.button a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="button"><a>Sub menu title 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Link1</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="button"><a>Sub menu title 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Link4</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="button"><a>Sub menu title 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your CSS:

```
.button {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: try and answer me